# Amazon Textract async calls unable to send notification to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am using Amazon Textract to perform OCR asynchronously. While everything works and a JobId is generated, the SNS notification is not generated.

I have verified that I have the correct,

1. Topic name - starts with AmazonTextract
2. Service Role with trust policy Textract is passed
3. Access Logging is enabled in SNS to check for 100% sample rate

I recreated it multiple times and followed the official documentation still have the same error.

Reference guide I followed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async-roles.html

Below is my input param

```
const input = {
    DocumentLocation: {
      S3Object: {
        // S3Object
        Bucket: "example-123456789012",
        Name: "example.pdf",
      },
      NotificationChannel: { // NotificationChannel
        SNSTopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:AmazonTextractTopic", // required
        RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/AmazonTextractServiceRole", // required
      },
    },
    FeatureTypes: [
      // FeatureTypes // required
      "TABLES" || "FORMS",
    ],
  };
```

Comment: what is the error message? what is your topic type(SQS, HTTPS, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

The more likely this is due to the permission issue. First try to narrow down the issue by separating `Textract` vs `sns/sqs`.

1. try manually publishing message into the SNS topic and see the message is populating in the SQS queue. If this doesnt work. Add nessary permission to sqs queue. The policy should be like below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:<YOUR_QUEUE_NAME>"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1692505611089",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:<YOUR_QUEUE_NAME>"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Once you make sure the first step is done, then check the lambda has correct permission to execute Textract, Access S3 ( if the object is in the S3 etc)

I tried with this and works with below Roles and policy.

DemoTextractRole:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "textract.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:textract:*:<ACCOUNT_ID>:*"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "<ACCOUNT_ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

QueuePolicy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:<YOUR_QUEUE_NAME>"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1692505611089",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:<YOUR_QUEUE_NAME>"
    }
  ]
}
```

LambdaRole:

```
FullPermission on S3
FullPermission on Textract
CloudWatch logs default policy
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and switching from FIFO SNS to a Standard SNS resolved the issue for me.